# SAP UI5 : binding JSON model data to detail view

Tags: data-binding, sapui5

I'm trying to display the data of a JSON file into the detail view file. As I'm new to SAP UI 5, I don't understand why I get the error : "oModel.createKey is not a function" in the console.

Can anyone explain me the cause of this error please ?

I searched for some solutions and this is what I did for the moment.

Here is the **main.view.xml** file :

```
                    <Table id="tab1" items="{path: 'articles>/Articles'}">
                        <columns>
                            <Column width="11rem">
                                <Label text="ID" />
                            </Column>
                            <Column width="11rem">
                                <Label text="Description" />
                            </Column>
                            <Column width="11rem">
                                <Label text="Date début de validité" />
                            </Column>
                            <Column width="11rem">
                                <Label text="Date fin de validité" />
                            </Column>
                            <Column width="11rem">
                                <Label text="Montant" />
                            </Column>
                        </columns>
                        <ColumnListItem press=".onPress" type="Navigation">
                            <Text text="{articles>id}" />
                            <Text text="{articles>description}" />
                            <Text text="{articles>debutValidite}" />
                            <Text text="{articles>finValidite}" />
                            <Text text="{articles>prix}" />
                        </ColumnListItem>
                    </Table>
```

The **main.controller.js** file :

```
    onInit: function () {
        var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
        oModel.loadData("./model/Articles.json");
        this.getView().setModel(oModel,"articles");
    },
    
    onPress: function(oEvent){
        var oItem = oEvent.getSource();
        var oContext = oItem.getBindingContext("articles");
        var sKeyId = oContext.getObject("id");
        var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
        oRouter.navTo("detail", {articleId: sKeyId});
```

The **detail.view.xml file** :

```
                    <f:SimpleForm id="form1">
                        <!--<f:content>-->
                            <Label text="ID"/>
                            <Text text="{articles>id'}"/>
                            <Label text="Description"/>
                            <Text text="{articles>description}"/>
                            <Label text="Date début de validité"/>
                            <Text text="{articles>debutValidite}"/>
                            <Label text="Date fin de validite"/>
                            <Text text="{articles>finValidite}"/>
                            <Label text="Montant"/>
                            <Text text="{articles>prix}"/>
                        <!--</f:content>-->
                    </f:SimpleForm>
```

The **detail.controller.js** file :

```
onInit: function () {
        var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
        oRouter.getRoute("detail").attachPatternMatched(this._onObjectMatched, this);

    },
_onObjectMatched: function (oEvent){
        
        var oModel = this.getView("detail").getModel("articles");
        console.log(oModel);
        var that= this;
        
        var sKeyId = oEvent.getParameter("arguments").articleId;
        console.log(sKeyId);

        oModel.dataLoaded().then(function(){
            var sPath = oModel.createKey("/Articles", {
                id: sKeyId  
            });
            that.getView().bindElement({ path: sPath});
        });
},
        


    onBack: function () {
        var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
        oRouter.navTo("main");
    }
```

The **Articles.json** file :

```
{
"Articles": [{
        "id": "AR00000111",
        "description": "Pièce de rechange",
        "debutValidite": "01.02.2020",
        "finValidite": "01.05.2021",
        "prix": "150"
    }, {
        "id": "AR00000112",
        "description": "Chaise",
        "debutValidite": "01.03.2020",
        "finValidite": "01.05.2021",
        "prix": "200"
    }, {
        "id": "AR00000113",
        "description": "Pièce de rechange",
        "debutValidite": "01.02.2020",
        "finValidite": "01.09.2021",
        "prix": "250"
    }

]
```

}

And the **manifest** file :

```
    "sap.ui5": {
    
    ...
    "models": {
        "i18n": {
            "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
            "settings": {
                "bundleName": "demo.testdemo.i18n.i18n"
            }
        },
        "articles": {
            "preload": true,
            "type": "sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel",
            "uri": "model/Articles.json"
        }
        ...
        "routes": [{
            "name": "main",
            "pattern": "",
            "target": ["main"]
        }, {
            "name": "detail",
            "pattern": "detail/{articleId}",
            "target": ["detail"]
        }],
        "targets": {
            "main": {
                "viewName": "main"
            },
            "detail": {
                "viewName": "detail"
            }
        }
```

Here is the detail.view.xml :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvPbL.png

And the main.view.xml :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0A5tf.png

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it your model is a JSONModel. JSONModels do not have the method `createKey`. This method only exists in the class `ODataModel`.

Instead you have to work with the JSON structure. So if you have an array you have to use the indices.

```js
const iIndex = oModel.getProperty("/Articles").findIndex(article => article.id === sKeyId);
const sPath = `/Articles/${iIndex}`;
```

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. I understand better now, and I have not yet dealt with the subject of oDataModel