# SAPUI5 : data from JSON not displayed in detail view page without errors in the developper tools

Tags: data-binding, sapui5

I'm trying to display the data of a JSON file into the detail view page. When I click on an item of the table, the details of this item should be displayed in the detail view page, but it don't. As I'm new to SAP UI 5, I don't understand what are the reasons for this mistake.

But in the developper tools, I can see the arrays of my data.

Can anyone explain me the cause of this error please ?

I searched for some solutions and this is what I did for the moment.

**main.view.xml**:

```
                    <Table id="tab1" items="{path: '/Articles'}">
                        <columns>
                            <Column width="11rem">
                                <Label text="ID" />
                            </Column>
                            <Column width="11rem">
                                <Label text="Description" />
                            </Column>
                            <Column width="11rem">
                                <Label text="Date début de validité" />
                            </Column>
                            <Column width="11rem">
                                <Label text="Date fin de validité" />
                            </Column>
                            <Column width="11rem">
                                <Label text="Montant" />
                            </Column>
                        </columns>
                        <ColumnListItem press=".onPress" type="Navigation">
                            <cells>
                                <Text text="{id}" />
                                <Text text="{description}" />
                                <Text text="{debutValidite}" />
                                <Text text="{finValidite}" />
                                <Text text="{prix}" />
                            </cells>
                        </ColumnListItem>
                    </Table>
```

**main.controller.js**:

```
    onPress: function (oEvent) {
        var oItem = oEvent.getSource();
        console.log(oItem);
        var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
        oRouter.navTo("detail", {
            ID: oItem.getBindingContext().getProperty("id")
        });
    },
```

**detail.view.xml:**

```
               <content>
                    <f:SimpleForm id="form1" editable="false" layout="ResponsiveGridLayout" labelSpanL="3" labelSpanM="3" emptySpanL="4" emptySpanM="4"
                        columnsL="1" columnsM="1">
                        <f:content>
                            <Label text="ID"/>
                            <Text text="{id'}"/>
                            <Label text="Description"/>
                            <Text text="{description}"/>
                            <Label text="Date début de validité"/>
                            <Text text="{debutValidite}"/>
                            <Label text="Date fin de validite"/>
                            <Text text="{finValidite}"/>
                            <Label text="Montant"/>
                            <Text text="{prix}"/>
                        </f:content>
                    </f:SimpleForm>
                </content>
```

**detail.controller.js:**

```
    onInit: function () {
        var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
        oRouter.getRoute("detail").attachPatternMatched(this._onObjectMatched, this);
    },

    _onObjectMatched: function (oEvent) {
        var sObjectPath = "/Articles/"+oEvent.getParameter("arguments").ID;
        this._bindView(sObjectPath);
        console.log(sObjectPath);
    },

    _bindView: function (sObjectPath) {
        var oView = this.getView();
        oView.bindElement(sObjectPath);
        console.log(oView.bindElement(sObjectPath));
    },

    onBack: function () {
        var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
        oRouter.navTo("main");
    }
```

In the **Component.js** file :

```
var oModel = new JSONModel();
oModel.loadData("./model/Articles.json");
this.setModel(oModel);
```

In the **manifest.json** file:

```
    "routes": [{
            "name": "main",
            "pattern": "",
            "target": "main"
        }, {
            "name": "detail",
            "pattern": "detail/{ID}",
            "target": "detail"
        }],
        "targets": {
            "main": {
                "viewName": "main",
                "viewLevel": 1
            },
            "detail": {
                "viewName": "detail",
                "viewLevel": 2
            }
        }
```

**Articles.json:**

```
{
"Articles": [{
        "id": "AR00000111",
        "description": "Pièce de rechange",
        "debutValidite": "01.02.2020",
        "finValidite": "01.05.2021",
        "prix": "150"
    }, {
        "id": "AR00000112",
        "description": "Chaise",
        "debutValidite": "01.03.2020",
        "finValidite": "01.05.2021",
        "prix": "200"
    }, {
        "id": "AR00000113",
        "description": "Pièce de rechange",
        "debutValidite": "01.02.2020",
        "finValidite": "01.09.2021",
        "prix": "250"
    }

]
```

}

[developper_tools_1.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92bTk.png)

[developper_tools_2.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sHZx.png)

[main_view.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PL6kI.png)

[detail_view.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NRDX.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SAP UI5 : binding JSON model data to detail view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69813959/sap-ui5-binding-json-model-data-to-detail-view)

Comment: No it didn't work, I delete my project and restarted again. I still keep searching for the source of error.

Comment: Well the source of error is using the wrong binding path.

Answer (score 0):

In your Detail.view.xml, could you try to remove the single quote in your text element ?

```
<Label text="ID"/>
<Text text="{id'}"/>
```

{id'} => {id}

```
<Label text="ID"/>
<Text text="{id}"/>
```

Check if it works now.